# Apply a function to several columns in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I have the following function:

```py
def remove_outlier(dfIn, colName):
    q1 = dfIn[colName].quantile(0.10)
    q3 = dfIn[colName].quantile(0.90)
    iqr = q3-q1 
    fenceLow = q1 - 1.5 * iqr
    fenceHigh = q3 + 1.5 * iqr
    dfOut = dfIn.loc[(dfIn[colName] > fenceLow) & (dfIn[colName] < fenceHigh)]
    return dfOut
```

I would like to apply the function to multiple columns in a data frame independently (one by one), without calling the function several times.

What is the most efficient way to do this? Or could the function be changed to pass a list of column names?

Comment: What do u mean with "without calling the function several times"? You get quantiles per column, therefore you have to call it multiple times. Do you want to have a single function for all columns to improve readability? Do you want to increase performace? what is your goal?

Comment: Ideally both if possible, but mainly readability. Many thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to change it in order to pass a list of column names, but could not get it to work unfortunately

Comment: Your q1 and q3 need to be 0.25 and 0.75 respectively for the actual iqr. else barely any outliers will be removed. Also, this will take 2 apply functions.. one on axis 0 and one on axis 1. Check my answer below. I modified your function and put a 2 line code after function definition to get you what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in 2 apply's. **In this solution, outliers are detected for each column separately and them rows containing an outlier for any column are removed individually.**

Assume this dataset. I modified your function and fixed the q1 and q3 values to what it should be.

```
    A   B     C   D
0   1   100   2   3
1   1   200   4   5
2   1   12000 4   7
3   2   100   22  2
4   2   200   3   1
```

```
#Modified function
def get_outliers(l):
    #if you keep 0.1 and 0.75 then pretty much no outliers will be filtered
    #q1 is 0.25 quantile and q3 is 0.75 quantile
    q1 = l.quantile(0.25)  
    q3 = l.quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1
    fenceLow = q1 - 1.5 * iqr
    fenceHigh = q3 + 1.5 * iqr
    return [~(i>=fenceLow and i<=fenceHigh) for i in l]
```

The first step is to get an apply function to get limits on columns and get a list of boolean values for each column.

```
outliers = df.apply(get_outliers)
```

```
        A       B       C       D
0   False   False   False   False
1   False   False   False   False
2   False   True    False   False
3   False   False   True    False
4   False   False   False   False
```

The second step is to find the rows where any one of the values is True and drop them.

```
df[~outliers.apply(lambda x:any(x), axis=1)]
```

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   100 2   3
1   1   200 4   5
4   2   200 3   1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, all columns should be treated independently, as the data ranges contained in them varies significantly. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: all the columns are treated differently in my code. The iqr is calculated for each column and it returns booleans for each column separately. Post that rows that contain an outlier are removed

Comment: More specifically, outliers are detected for each column separately, and then removed for each row separately. Different data ranges for different columns are handled in this solution.

Comment: ah yes, sorry, understood now :) thank you very much!

Comment: Edited the dataset to include different data ranges for making the solution more clear